# How to create POJO dynamically in Spring-Framework(Java)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

For example consider a class 'Person' with variables "name,address,phone,email,salary". I want to create a Person POJO dynamically at run-time based on results of another collection which contains names of the fields and its type.

```
public class Person
 {
 //variables

private String name;
private String address;
private String phone;
private String email;
private int salary;

public String getName(){
 return name;
}
public void setName(){
 this.name = name;
}
public String getAddress(){
 return address;
}
public void setAddress(){
 this.address = address;
}

public String getPhone(){
 return phone;
}
public void setPhone(){
 this.phone = phone;
}
public String getEmail(){
 return email;
}
public void setEmail(){
 this.email = email;
}
public int getSalary(){
 return salary;
}
public void setSalary(){
 this.salary = salary;
}
}
```

results from collection is placed in HashMap which contains type and field name.Is their any way to generate POJO at run-time in spring based on it.